# React firebase error: where' is not defined query call firebase in react

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react with Firebase. But when I using where condition in query it show error:

```
  'where' is not defined
```

1. I have collection named **comapntList** and I have filed below:

   **id "2"
   name "ABC"**
2. Here is my firebase rule permission

   ```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write;
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Here is the firebase config:

```
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
    const firebase = {
      apiKey: "xx",
      authDomain: "xx",
      projectId: "xx",
      storageBucket: "xx",
      messagingSenderId: "x",
      appId: "xx",
      measurementId: "G-J7CJWNMETH"

    };

    const firebaseApp  = initializeApp(firebase);
     const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
     const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
    const auth = getAuth();
     
    export { firebaseApp , auth,db,storage };
```

3. Here is code:

   ```
         const collection_ref = collection(db, "comapntList")
          const q = query(collection_ref, where("id", "==", "2"))

          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

          if (querySnapshot.size === 1) {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

            console.log(doc.data());
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Document not found or multiple documents found.');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
   ```

what is the wrong of my code?

Comment: It looks like you're not importing `where`. Add it to the same place where you import `query`, `collection`, and `getDocs`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for reply I have improt import { collection,  getDocs,doc, getDoc,  ,query} from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db,storage } from '../../../firebase'

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have also updated firebase config info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `import { collection, getDocs,doc, getDoc, ,query}`, you're not importing `where` - which explains why the compiler can't find it.

To be able to use `where`, add it to your `import` statement for Firestore:

```
import { collection, getDocs,doc, getDoc, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [running simple and complex queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries), which usually shows the necessary imports in its code snippets.